ITMS-91054: Invalid API category declaration - The PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy file at the “PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy” path contains “NSFileModificationDate”
We noticed one or more issues with a recent submission for App Store review for the following app:
Rasen Horse
Version 1.0.6
Build 135

Please correct the following issues and upload a new binary to App Store Connect.
ITMS-91054: Invalid API category declaration - The PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy file at the “PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy” path contains “NSFileModificationDate” as the value for a NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType key, which is invalid. Values for NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType keys in any privacy manifest must be valid API categories. For more details about this policy, including a list of required reason APIs and approved reasons for usage, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api.
Apple Developer Relations
I am using React native with Expo When I tried to publish the app in the app store it rejected by sending this mail I mentioned above. Please help me with this issue.
